# How to get polyline latitude and longitude by click on polyline android?

Tags: android, google-maps, click, location, polyline

I have set Polyline click listener like this :

```
  map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                int strokeColor = polyline.getColor() ^ 0x0000CC00;
                polyline.setColor(strokeColor);
                Log.e("TAG", "Polyline points @ " + polyline.getPoints());
                Toast.makeText(Draw_Route.this, "Polyline klick: " + polyline.getPoints(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

But i need to get coordinates of that point when user click on polyline, i also used this code to get the codrinates -- >

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng clickCoords) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Found @ " + clickCoords.latitude + " " + clickCoords.longitude);
            }
        });
```

But it only works when i click on map, i need to get that point coordinates on click on polyline so please help me, how to get that.

Thanks

Comment: I am in need of the same requirement.. Can you please help me out

Comment: did you find answer ? im stuck with this too